# Collect data in views and output in head

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a helper that collects data from multiple views:

```
# application_helper.rb
def data
  @data ||= []
end
```

In my HTML, I want to add data to this helper. This should be possible from within the layout, views and partials:

```
# layout.html.erb
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <section><% data << "section data" %></section>
    <%= yield %>
    <footer><% data << "footer data" %></footer>
  </body>
</html>

# my_view.html.erb (which is rendered with yield)
<h1>My View</h1>
<% data << "view data" %>
```

The problem is, that the data should be rendered as a data attribute on the body tag, e.g.

```
<body data-test="<%= data.to_json %>">
```

Of course, this would render an empty array, because at this point of time, the array is not filled yet.

I tried it with

```
<body data-test="<%= yield(:data) %>">
  ...

  <% content_for(:data) do %>
     <%= data.to_json %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

but this also doesn't work. It only works, when I put the `content_for` call inside a view. And furthermore, I only get `view data` but not `section data` or `footer data`. So it seems that only data that is added within my view is rendered, not the data that I add within my layout.

**How would something like this be done? Rendering data at the top of an html page, that is collected later in the document?**

Comment: Rails helper shouldn't be used for this (they have absolutely another meaning). I think, that you should do this with pure JS. But... your task is very weird and I think about a possibility, that you choose not the best solution in general. What should be done with this data-test after it's filled?

Comment: Its a very simplified example to demonstrate the use case. Actually I'm collecting data points throughout the rendering of my page that should be rendered as nearly as to the top of the document as possible, so that a a JS snippet can pick them up and send them to our server. Background is, that I also want to send the data, even when the page hasn't been fully loded, so it has to be at the top.

Comment: Why you collect this data during view rendering? Just collect all of it during request processing on the backend side (controller/model layer) and then put it in the data

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body data-test="<%= content_for(:data) %>">
    <section></section>
    <%= yield %>
    <footer>></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

[`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) can be used to both store content for later use and provide dynamic blocks since subsequent calls to `content_for` concatenate.

Lets say we are rendering `users/show:`

```
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
<% content_for(:data) { @user.name } %>
<% content_for(:data) { ", " + @user.username } %>
```

This would give

```
<body data-test="john doe, john_doe">
```

However its use for passing data structures is questionable since its just a string buffer.

A better alternative is to gather the data beforehand and use JSON to pass the data into javascript.

Comment: As I said, from within the view it is no problem. But what if you set the data outside the `yield` block, directly in the layout, say within the `<footer>`?

Comment: Not sure, you would have to test it. But its not a very good idea from the get go as it adds far to much logic in your views which should be almost purely declarative.

Comment: I would say that its a textbook example of an x/y problem. You're too focused on your solution using views to consider bettter options.